# Fabric plugin 1.26.0 incompatibility

Tags: android, gradle, google-fabric

When upgrading Fabric gradle plugin to 1.26.0, I cannot build my project due to the following error:

```
Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsProdAdminRelease, class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask, com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@258f7e6c] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.
```

I reverted back to 1.25.4, not sure if it's a bug or something from my side.

https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#september-21-2018

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as well. Use 1.25.4 for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric released a bad update, fixed in version 1.26.1

For future reference, monitor the below link to check for new updates:

https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin